# Participative maps for collecting geographic information?

Tags: web-mapping, web-gis, data-collection, crowdsourcing, joomla

I'm looking for a simple way to collect information for a participative plans (regarding landscape) and show them on Google Maps.

I'm thinking to a small web form for asking information to public (es: point of interest, ), then they have to digtize the refered point, line or polygon. After submit, the information are showed in a map.

Any ideas? Like using Joomla extension or similar.

Comment: Doesn't Open Streets Map already allow or require such participatory mapping? How is your project different? Is it because you're restricted to using Google Maps? Maybe explain why you need GM instead of OSM.

Comment: Yes but we need a simple tool dedicated to our work. Effectively, we don't need GM, but an orthophoto as a base where the public can "draw"  elements of the landscape.

Comment: Why not edit that extra info (even though i'm unsure what it means) into the question?

Answer (score 0):

Check out Crowd Map from [Ushahidi](http://www.ushahidi.com/). It's an open source crowd sourcing map application. It definitely does points, not sure about lines and polygons. They also have a hosted version.